# Using ASP.net credentials to log in from a WinForms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, asp.net-membership, credentials

We have an ASP.net application but some screens are deemed too slow to use by our users.
As a result, we are trying to provide a WinForms-based alternative to those data-input centric screens so we can use richer controls like Grids with immediate screen updates and feedback for the user.

Ideally, I would like the users to login to the WinForms application using the same credentials they use in the ASP.net application?

Is it possible?
I've found this post ( [.Net authentication for both web and winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172069/net-authentication-for-both-web-and-winforms) ) but it isn't really answering the question from my point of view... 
We are not using WebServices, or WCF at the moment and do not plan to use it unless it is really the only way to achieve this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The membership / user data are 'just tables'. So you could use similar connectionstrings (/providers)  (if your db security is setup to allow this). Also have a look here, if you like: http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0511031

Comment: Can you please expand on this? As far as I know, the passwords are hashed etc and I don't know how so I can't compare my password against them?

Comment: Have a look here as well. http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2006/01/12/80905.aspx  I'd imagine (but I'm not sure) the passwords would 'just work' for their owners as you'd expect.

Comment: The missing piece: How do you login to your ASP.NET?  Windows authentication or Forms?

Comment: Not Windows Authentication. standard ASP.net memberships user accounts.

Comment: If your application is too slow, switching to winforms will not solve that. It just replaces one problem with another problem.  You can speed up your application without switching its architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can, just add the same settings in your app.config that you have in your web.config to wire up the Membership provider, and reference System.Web.Security. Then you can use  Membership and Roles from your WinForms application.

See this article for a good example of how to do this: 
http://www.theproblemsolver.nl/usingthemembershipproviderinwinforms.htm

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tried this on a demo project and it worked great!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this article: [Unify Windows Forms and ASP.NET Providers for Credentials Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163807.aspx).

For even more information check out the links from this answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9e5192f4-4f44-4db6-aab8-8e79f2e667f8.