# How to use IsInRole from ASP.NET Membership in the Library dll

Tags: asp.net, dll, isinrole

Most Real world web applications have at least one dll library behind them. If we use the ASP.NET membership provider, how can we call the Roles.IsInRole method in the dll?

The possibility of referencing HttpContext is not good. Because, we have a few console application tools that use the same dll to complete a few bulk operations.

Comment: This seems to be a design-problem. Can you please include any use case scenario how you want this to work in order to help you better ?

Comment: I recommend you watch this video about custom membership provider which may explain how MembershipProviders work and how they can be used using configuration. http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-189.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to decouple your Membership mechanism from ASP.NET.

There are some good resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784608/how-to-implement-security-component-in-windows-forms) on how to reference the ASP.NET Membership Provider from Windows Forms applications, which would work in the same way for console applications.

The best one is [here](http://www.theproblemsolver.nl/usingthemembershipproviderinwinforms.htm) (in VB.NET).

However, all suffer the same basic problem, which is that a malicious user could change their configuration to use their own authorisation database. (ASP.NET configuration is not available to users so we don't have the same problem there.)

So a better approach would be to either directly query the ASP.NET membership databases from your code in ADO.NET (which isn't hard: they're fairly straightforward) or to roll your own implementation of the underlying Membership Provider interfaces (detailer on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)). You could then have the ASP.NET Membership Provider call your own code to establish if a user is in a role, and use this code in the same way from your console application.

Comment: You can encrypt the section of your web.config using DPAPI provider. And you should never attempt to query asp.net membership database directly. I'd consider this as bad practice.